# Excel - prefix/suffix text on field after text entry

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would like to enter a string of text into a field and once I have hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to have a constant prefix and suffix added to the text - e.g. if I type *BuyLinux* or *InsultBill* into a cell and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> (or <kbd>Tab</kbd>) to commit the text, the field then says *NeverBuyLinuxEver* or *NeverInsultBillEver*, and so on.
I have looked at `CONCAT`, `REPLACE` and `SUBSTITUTE` but can not make this work (I get the *Circular Reference* error).
Any clues, gurus?

Comment: You can't use formulas to change cells you edited manually. You can use VBA (have a look on [Worksheet.Change event](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change). Or as a workaround use another cell where you display the updated values.

Comment: Do you want the cell to **contain** that string, or to **display** that string.  For the former, you will need a VBA event-triggered macro; for the latter, you can use cell number formatting (if it will apply to anything typed in) or conditional formatting (if it will apply only to certain strings).

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Private Const prefix As String = "-=prefix=-"
Private Const postfix As String = "-=postfix=-"

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
' the flag to avoid recursive calls
Static busy As Boolean
' If this call is recursive then do nothing
If busy Then Exit Sub
' Mark that the action is now performed
busy = True
' When some value on the worksheet is changed we check
' that only one cell is selected (not multicell range)
' and this cell is in column 1 (column A)
If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    ' If one cell in column A is altered, update its value
    Target.Value = prefix & Target.Value & postfix
End If
' Drop execution mark
busy = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not iterate through the cells in the Intersect of Target and the desired range? `Application.EnableEvents = False` will take care of that.

Comment: @Jeeped OP says "enter string and press Enter". So multicell must not.